# Serializar un arraylist lectura de fichero

Tags: java, archivo, arraylist, serialización

Tengo problemas con mi código. Verán, el programa si me permite leer el objeto (de tipo *ArrayList*) sin embargo, cuando quiero escribirlo me salta el error de `IOException`. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Para este ejercicio me piden usar el `ObjectOutputStream` para lectura y el `ObjectInputStream` para escritura.

```
public class Cliente {
    
    private ArrayList <Registrado> usuariosR = new ArrayList<Registrado>();
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void menu_comprador(){
        int opcion;
        do{
        System.out.println("\t\tMENÚ DE COMPRADOR\t\t");
        System.out.println("1. Registrar usuario");
        System.out.println("2. Iniciar sesión");
        System.out.println("3. Ingresar como invitado");
        System.out.println("4. Volver ");
        System.out.print("\n-> Digite opción: ");
        opcion = leer.nextInt();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1: 
                guardarDatosRegistrado();
                break;
            case 2: 
                mostrarArchivo();
                break;
            case 3:
                
                break;
            case 4: System.out.println("volviendo");
                break; 
        }
        }while(opcion != 4);
    }
     public Registrado registrarR(){
        String nombre,user,pass,direccion;
        int DNI;
        long telefono;
        System.out.println("Digite los siguientes datos ");
        System.out.print("\n Nombre: ");
        nombre = leer.next();
        System.out.print("\n DNI: ");
        DNI = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n Usuario: ");
        user = leer.next();
        System.out.print("\n Contraseña: ");
        pass = leer.next();
        System.out.print("\n Ingrese su numero telefónico: ");
        telefono = leer.nextLong();
        leer.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n Ingrese su dirección: ");
        direccion = leer.next();
        Registrado r = new Registrado(telefono,direccion,nombre, DNI, user, pass);
        return r; 
    }
     public void guardarDatosRegistrado(){
        Registrado r = registrarR();
        ArrayList<Registrado> aux2 = rescatarRegistrados();
        if(aux2==null){
            try{
            usuariosR.add(r);
            ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:...\\usuariosR.txt"));
            salida.writeObject(usuariosR);
            salida.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error¡¡¡¡¡");
            }
            System.out.println("Creado de forma exitosa");
        }else{
            try{
            aux2.add(r);
            ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:...\\usuariosR.txt"));
            salida.writeObject(aux2);
            salida.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error¡¡¡¡¡");
            }
            System.out.println("Creado de forma exitosa");
        }
        
    }
    public void mostrarArchivo(){
        try{
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:...\\usuariosR.txt"));
            ArrayList<Registrado> r = (ArrayList<Registrado>)entrada.readObject();
            System.out.println("TAMAÑO "+ r.size());
            mostrarDatos(r);
            entrada.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            //EL ERROR SUCEDE ACA
            System.out.println("ERROR a");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println("ERROR b");
        }
     }
        public void mostrarDatos(ArrayList<Registrado> r){
        Iterator <Registrado> it = r.iterator();
        Registrado re = null;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            re = it.next();
            System.out.println("nombre "+ re.getNombre());
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Registrado> rescatarRegistrados(){
        try{
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:...\\usuariosR.txt"));
            ArrayList<Registrado> r1 = (ArrayList<Registrado>)entrada.readObject();
            return r1;
        }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            return null;
        }  
    }
```

Lo que hago en el método `rescatarRegistrados`, es que al momento de ejecutarlo otra vez, el programa pueda recuperar todos los objetos dentro del arraylist que inserté en la ejecución anterior. Es por eso que retorna un `ArrayList(Registrado)`, caso contrario retornará un `null`, esto con el fin de poder hacer la persistencia. Gracias.

A través de `e.printStackTrace()` salió este error:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: Login.Registrado; no valid constructor

Además luego me salta en la línea de `ArrayList<Registrado> r = (ArrayList<Registrado>)entrada.readObject()` un error.

Bueno he buscado en internet sobre el problema y al parecer radica en que mi clase registrado hereda de otras dos clases y esto interfiere con la serialización, dejare el código de la clase Registrado y sus clases padre.

```
public class Registrado extends Usuario implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long telefono;
    private String direccion;

    public Registrado(long telefono, String direccion, String nombre, int DNI, String user, String pass) {
        super(nombre, DNI, user, pass);
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }                                                                                        
    public abstract class Usuario extends Persona {

    public Usuario(String nombre, int DNI, String user, String pass) {
        super(nombre, DNI, user, pass);
    }
    
    }                                                                                  
    public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int DNI;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    public Persona(String nombre, int DNI, String user, String pass) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.DNI = DNI;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Es `"C:...\\usuariosR.txt"` la ruta real que está en el programa? En todo caso, dentro del catch puedes hacer `e.printStackTrace();` que mostrará por consola mucha más información del error (en que línea salta, un mensaje más informativo, etc..)

Comment: Hola que tal, en realidad la ruta es mas larga solo que para fines didacticos lo puse asi, lo he intentado con printStacktrace() y me sale esto java.io.InvalidClassException: Login.Registrado; no valid constructor; además luego me salta en la línea de                           
   ArrayList<Registrado> r = (ArrayList<Registrado>)entrada.readObject();

Comment: Hola ¿La clase Registrado, tiene un constructor sin argumentos? public Registrado (){}. Ese parece ser el error. Es una clase interna?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, el constructor si esta con sus parámetros, indagando en internet el error radica en que la excepcion InvalidClassException se lanza cuando la herencia esta involucrada en el programa, en mi caso la clase registrados hereda de otras dos clases (una abstracta) es por eso que me sale error

Answer (score 0):

bueno ya pude resolver el problema, solo se tenia que poner el serializable en la clase padre :)

```
public class Persona implements Serializable{
private String nombre;
private int DNI;
private String user;
private String pass;

public Persona(String nombre, int DNI, String user, String pass) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.DNI = DNI;
    this.user = user;
    this.pass = pass;
}
```